# Viewing a calculation in realtime

Tags: java, square-root

I was wondering whether or not it would be possible to display the answer to a calculation in JAVA while it is being calculated.  Let me explain:

If I were to square root 7 (√7), there are more than a million digits (refer to http://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/sqrt7.1mil).  I am sure that this would take some time for the computer to compute so would it be possible to display the values as they are being computed?

I could have a text box in a GUI - the variable could be named `calculatedTextBox` which the value should keep updating to.

Is this possible and how would you go around doing this?

Many thanks!

Comment: sqrt(7) is an irrational number thus having an _infinite_ number of digits.

Comment: @collapsar I am trying to collect as many digits as possible while viewing them in real time.  I understand that it has an infinite number of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find a [spigot algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm) that caluclates one digit after another and then append digits to your result display as you find them. (To find an algorithm, you'd have to ask on mathoverflow or use google.)

Comment: What exactly is a spigot algorithm and how can I use it in JAVA?

Comment: Just click on the word "spigot algorithm" to get to the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite simple. Imagine that you are solving problem 1/3 so in first iteration you get 0 (update result to 0.). next iteration will be 1*10 / 3 = 3 (update result to 0.3) next iteration will be 1*10 / 3 (update result to 0.33) etc. You can use recursion for this computing and in every recursion step you will update result. For **sqrt** you go with same way just have different problem to solve especially [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots)

Comment: Isn't 1/3 ~ 0.33(3) ? not 0.99(9)